# Resizing buttons in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using my layout code as

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:background="@android:drawable/bottom_bar"
    android:paddingLeft="4.0dip" android:paddingTop="5.0dip"
    android:paddingRight="4.0dip" android:paddingBottom="1.0dip"
    android:id="@+id/select_names_tags_ll1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    
    <Button android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0.0dip"
            android:text="ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="10.0dip"
            android:text="KKKKK"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="10.0dip"
            android:text="YYY"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        

android:padding="5dp"/>
```

its output as
[image]

I want to fix width of buttons depends on their text length. How it will be possible?

Comment: remove weight tag and give wrap_content for width

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to set the width of the buttons as follows:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

and you have to remove the following from the buttons:

```
android:layout_weight="1.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

That should help for sure. For more customization try using layout_weight and weightsum attributes